# After signaling a waiting condition variable, when the thread will acquire the lock? What determines it?

Tags: c++, pthreads, condition-variable

After searching on the web, and reading the question answers on the stackoverflow, i couldn't find the answer of my question.

The wait is called in thread B, and it unlocks the mutex, allowing others access to the condition variable (for signalling). Then, when the condition variable is signalled in thread A , thread B wakes up and Thread B locks the mutex again.

When the thread A wakes up thread B by signalling the condition variable, thread B is waked up, lock the mutex.

I understand from the tutorials that, whenever thread B is signaled, it immediately locks the mutex. However the examples are the opposite of this, when thread B is signaled,and waked up, thread A continue to execute, some times later thread B locks the mutex.

**My question is when does thread B(consumer in the below example) lock the mutex? Just at the moment that thread B takes the signal? Or does it depend on the thread scheduler?**

I didn't find any explanations about that.

I am thinking about the case of below example :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;

int buffer[100];

int loops = 5;
int length = 0;

void *producer(void *arg) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    buffer[length++] = i;
    printf("producer length %d\n", length);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(length == 0) {
        printf(" consumer waiting...\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
    int item = buffer[--length];
    printf("Consumer %d\n", item);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, 0);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, 0);

    pthread_t pThread, cThread;
    pthread_create(&pThread, 0, producer, 0);
    pthread_create(&cThread, 0, consumer, 0);
    pthread_join(pThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(cThread, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
consumer waiting...
producer length 1
producer length 2
producer length 3
producer length 4
producer length 5
Consumer 4
Consumer 3
Consumer 2
Consumer 1
Consumer 0
```

THanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of a condition variable is that of releasing the lock and waiting (atomically) and then re-acquiring the lock when the thread is signaled. In your code, one thread is signaling the other while holding the mutex, and the implication is that the woken up thread is going to enter the wait queue in the mutex until the other thread releases the mutex.

Comment: But in each for loop, producer unlocks the mutex. It iterates 5 times, locking and unlocking mutex 5 times.  My question is why doesn't consumer lock the mutex immediately, when producer unlock the mutex?

Comment: The first thread might be completing before the second thread is created in the first place, or there might be some other reason that is unrelated to the condition variable. Try reverting the order in which you create the threads to rule out the option of the first thread completing before the second thread has a chance of doing anything at all.

Comment: You said that "In your code, one thread is signaling the other while holding the mutex, and the implication is that the woken up thread is going to enter the wait queue in the mutex until the other thread releases the mutex."  In all examples on the web, one thread signals the other which holds the mutex because mutex and conditional variables are used together. I think your implication is true not only for my example but also all examples including mutex-condition variables. In order to signal, a thread locks the mutex , which i see on many examples. If i am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @oiyio: You don't need to hold the mutex to signal a condition variable, it is common to do so, but you don't need to. But that is almost unrelated, the fact is that one thread *owns* the mutex at this time, it wakes the other but the condition wait won't come back to the caller until it has acquired the mutex. The mutex cannot be aquired as the other thread has it... If the woken thread proceeded immediately into the critical section without acquiring the mutex there would be *two* threads in the critical region (bad), and it would eventually release a mutex it is not holding (bad)

Comment: Whenever producer unlocks the mutex, isn't it a requirement that consumer locks the mutex, in this example?

Comment: @oiyio: You are mixing things :)  You don't need the `signal` to happen while you are holding the mutex.  In the simple producer-consumer implementation you have with a single mutex everyone needs to block (not necessarily for all of the time), but you can implement more fine grained locking strageties with a mutex for each side of the queue and an additional mutex for the shared state between producers and consumers that would allow one producer and one consumer accessing the queue at the same time. In that implementation, producers signal on a condition for the other end of the queue

Comment: I understand you. I don't need the signal while i am holding the mutex. To use mutex and conditional variables are not mandatory. But my question is for this example. In this example, consumer waits for signal. Think a new producer similar to the producer in this example. The difference is that the new producer does not lock any mutex, it signals the consumer. In this case, does consumer immediately lock the mutex? Or is it possible that producer continue to execute although there is no locking mutex etc in producer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72172/discussion-between-david-rodriguez-dribeas-and-oiyio).

Comment: When the producer unlocks the mutex, it immediately becomes *possible* for the consumer to start executing and lock the mutex - but it doesn't *have* to.   Unless you are using realtime scheduling and have given the consumer a higher priority, it's perfectly allowable - and in fact probable - that the producer will continue to execute for a while after unlocking the mutex, and in doing so it may well be able to re-lock the mutex again itself, before the consumer has a chance to run.

Comment: @caf: That is true, but if you look at this as part of a long lived process, where both producer and consumer have had a chance to run, the consumer will be waiting in the mutex when the producer signals, even if it is not give CPU time right now, when the producer hits the same mutex, and assuming a mutex that guarantees no starvation, it will have to wait until the consumer progresses into the critical section and leaves it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Default pthreads mutexes *don't* make any starvation guarantees - they are not queued or FIFO.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas you just got owned homie

Answer (score 0):

Thread B (consumer) wakes up with the mutex already acquired, assuming `pthread_cond_unlock` returns successfully.  So you want to check for the return value (i.e. 0 = successful) to know whether the mutex was acquired.

Comment: In the example i supplied, consumer thread wakes up. But producer thread continues to execute. After producer finishes, consumer starts to execute.

Comment: The consumer thread doesn't wake up until after the producer thread is complete.  This is due to the thread scheduler.  Try increasing the loop count and you should see the two threads sharing the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem has been posted for 7 years, I still would like to explain it.

### What happen?

The situation you mentioned is called **spurious wakeup**.
A spurious wakeup happens when you wake a thread up knowing they may not be processed immediately, because the mutex is still hold in caller.
First, I don't think that create producer thread first is a good order, if you want to understand this question, because one situation is that produce finish its task before consumer start. So you can try to create the consumer thread before the produce thread.

### What if you forget wakeup the consumer thread?

You can try to comment out this line:

```c
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

You will find after printing "consumer waiting" and produce five times, the process is blocked due to consumer thread didn't be waked up.(Note:no every time is such situation, because producer may execute first even we create consumer first.) So we know producer thread is created first, then enter waiting process release the mutex and never get back due to not be waked up.
At this time, if we see process status using `ps -x`, we can see that the process status is `Sl+` which means it's a multi-threaded process and interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete).

For your question, **When the thread will acquire lock**. The answer is when the signal is sent. When the consumer thread is signaled, it will enter waiting queue for the mutex just like `@David Rodríguez - dribeas` said. If didn't get mutex it will be blocked, just like example above.

For you question **why doesn't consumer lock the mutex immediately, when producer unlock the mutex** is because the times you try is too less. If you loop 200 times, you may see consumer get lock.
A part of my result running your code modifying loop times:

```bash
producer length 34
producer length 35
Consumer 34
Consumer 33
```

Especially in one core cpu consumer thread can get lock **after producer release it** (not during sent signal), but such content switch is waste of time.
MY test code below:

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;

int buffer[1000];

int loops = 200;
int length = 0;

void *producer(void *arg) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    buffer[length++] = i;
    printf("producer length %d\n", length);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(length == 0) {
        printf(" consumer waiting...\n");
        // return zero due to spurious wakeup.
        int status=pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        printf("status code:%d\n",status);
    }
    int item = buffer[--length];
    printf("Consumer %d\n", item);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, 0);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, 0);

    pthread_t pThread, cThread;
    pthread_create(&cThread, 0, consumer, 0);
    pthread_create(&pThread, 0, producer, 0);
    pthread_join(pThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(cThread, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    return 0;
}
```

**So can we unlock mutex before broadcast/signal ?**
Not of all cases.
In your case, you can change the order of release lock and signal.Like this

```c
...
    printf("producer length %d\n", length);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
...
```

But if you need to access variable before signal, you cannot change order.
Like this.

```
lock(m);
counter--;
if(counter==0){
  signal(&con)
}
unlock(m)
```

In the case above, you cannot move `if` clause outside the lock scope, because the counter may change after unlock.
I hope this answer will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to add here my two cents with regards to a less-obvious implied behavior when working with pthread condition variable + a mutex. Considere the sequence below:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
pthread_con_wait(&cond,&m);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

As soon as the thread has waited on 'cond', it also automatically unlocks the mutex!! This is not obvious, and has caused a lot of confusion.